# How to enable tagging in the default autocomplete fields of the Django admin?

Tags: django, jquery-select2

I would like to enable [tagging (creating related objects on the fly)](https://select2.org/tagging) in the [autocomplete fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) of the Django admin.

Consider a model named `Task` that has a foreign key to a simple `Instruction` model with a single `TextField`:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    instructions = models.ForeignKey(
        "Instructions", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )

class Instructions(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=500)
```

The `Task` model may be displayed using an inline in other model admins (for instance `Project`).

So far I've managed to enable the tagging feature of the Select2 widget by setting `data-tags` in the `ModelForm`:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect

class TaskInlineModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        widgets = {
            "instructions": AutocompleteSelect(
                Task.instructions.field,
                admin_site=admin.site,
                attrs={"data-tags": "true"},    # <--- right here
            ),
            ...
        }
```

but when trying to save a form containing a `TaskInlineModelForm` and having typed a yet unseen value in the `instructions` field, Django complains about finding the typed value instead of an id

> Field 'id' expected a number but got "This is a brand new instructions that has never been seen".

How could this be solved so users can conveniently add new `Instructions` on the fly without using the mouse?

I am also open to a solution that turns `Task.instructions` into a simple `Textfield`, all I need is a fully fledged autocomplete widget with tagging enabled in the admin. The only reason it's currently a foreign key is because the autocomplete feature was implemented this way by the Django admin.

Comment: You need to have it as a simple TextField in both the model and the form (that is, in the form you only check that is a valid value, otherwhise you treat is as a normal text field).
You then need a template that creates the field using the code shown in your first link. You will have to create a list of all the existing tags and then pass it to the template, that will use this list to create the various <option> html elements.
In other words, you need to implement this by yourself using Django templates, HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Django's Select2 widget and customize it to handle the creation of new Instructions objects:

Create a custom form field that extends the ModelChoiceField and overrides the prepare_value method. This method will handle cases where the value is a string (representing a new Instruction) instead of an ID:

```
from django import forms

class TaggableModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        # If value is a string, assume it is a new Instruction and return 
it as the value
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        return super().prepare_value(value)
```

Update the TaskInlineModelForm to use the TaggableModelChoiceField for the instructions field:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AutocompleteSelect

class TaskInlineModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    instructions = TaggableModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Instructions.objects.all(),
        widget=AutocompleteSelect(
            Task.instructions.field,
            admin_site=admin.site,
            attrs={"data-tags": "true"},
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

TaggableModelChoiceField should override the default behavior of the field and allow it to handle both existing Instruction objects (using their IDs) and new Instruction values (as strings). When a string value is encountered, it should be treated as a new Instruction. If the value does not exist yet, it should be saved as a new instruction.

Hope this helps